# Preventing ERR_BLOCKED_BY_XSS_AUDITOR in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, http, xss

I have the following setup:

`GET /foo` - displays a form with a textarea containing markup which posts to `/bar`

`POST /bar` - generates a `ERR_BLOCKED_BY_XSS_AUDITOR` error in Chrome (started recently)

How can I get around that? I read that I should be able to use the `X-XSS-Protection: 0` header to get around this, but should I send that as a request header or a response header? On the `/foo` URL or the `/bar` one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome: ERR\_BLOCKED\_BY\_XSS\_AUDITOR details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249998/chrome-err-blocked-by-xss-auditor-details)

Answer (score 5):

You must send response header on the server side. For example Node.js with Express

```
res.header('X-XSS-Protection' , 0 );
```

Or for PHP

```
header("X-XSS-Protection: 0");
```

Comment: A response header from the GET or the POST?

Comment: It does not matter. This message about XSS protection is sent from server to client. The server tells browser something like "I trust in all your input fields so you shouldn't check it on your side".

Comment: OK, thanks. If it's an instruction to the browser to not check input fields, I'll guess it's with the GET that it needs to be sent.