# ckeditor change html code structure

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor

I am rendering a form with CKeditor and I noticed that a variable got from php that has a string value:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5EmbGL6nuIs" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

is changed in:

```
<iframe allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5EmbGL6nuIs" width="560"></iframe>
```

as you can see the order of the attributes are changed inside the iframe tag under the source CKeditor section.

How can I prevent this situation?

Comment: First of all you should make sure this question doesn't suffer from the [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/). *Why* do you want to prevent an alphabetical reordering of the attributes, given that their order doesn't matter to a browser?

Comment: The order matter for Chrome that throws an error related to xss. Do not know the reason but it works only with my order.

Comment: ...what error, verbatim, does Chrome throw, and when?

Comment: Chrome detected unusual code on this page and blocked it to protect your personal information (for example, passwords, phone numbers and credit cards).
Try visiting the site's homepage.
ERR_BLOCKED_BY_XSS_AUDITOR

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249998/chrome-err-blocked-by-xss-auditor-details Or done any other research into the issue before posting here?

Comment: Yes I have done other research off course. My solution was to do not allow order the iframe attributes because in this case Chrome do not complain