# Disabling XSS Filter for IE11 on BrowserStack

Tags: node.js, selenium, protractor, internet-explorer-11, browserstack

Greetins all,

I am working on cross-browser testing via browserstack. I have an inssue with Internet Explorer 11 or earlier versions. My test code requires me to send some scripts in the url. To be able to do this, cross-browser scripting, with IE11, I have to first `disable XSS Filter` on `IE11`. Does anyone know how to do this on `browserstack` for internet explorer. And I am not talking about going to settings and manually disabling. Is there a sort of capability setting for this on browserstack? Or what would be the best way to this? Thank you all for you help with this.

Best,

Comment: Does this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54210404/err-blocked-by-xss-auditor-when-downloading-file-using-selenium/54213843#54213843) help you?

Comment: It does but I am not sure how to iimplement this. I need to set `X-XSS-Protection: 0` using protractor or selenium wither with java or nodejs. What would be the correct line of code to set this.