# ERR_BLOCKED_BY_XSS_AUDITOR error in Google Chome - $.base64Encode

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, xss, blocked

i found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43249998/chrome-err-blocked-by-xss-auditor-details) but i am not allowed to comment so i have to ask a question here.
I am having exactly the same issue but i cant figure out how to embed the code within my code.
Here is my code with the json.html being the value that i need to encode as currently the HTML is causing troubles with Chrome.

```
jQuery('textarea[name=htmlcode]').val(json.html);
```

how do i work it out with the encode $.base64Encode ? Where do i need to place it?
I tried the below but it seems not working at all

```
jQuery('textarea[name=htmlcode]').val($.base64Encode(json.html);
```

Thanks

Comment: If you have access to the server side of things, then fixing this by just issuing the response header the other answer in that referred question mentions, would be way easier …

Comment: yes thanks, tried it but it is not working consistently, specifically on BRAVE and EPIC is not working at all. Any fixes for it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah, I didn’t know these chromium-based browsers handled that differently. Well, then back to the original approach. _“I tried the below but it seems not working at all”_ - in that original answer it is mentioned that they are using a jQuery plugin to provide that `base64Encode` method, so you would have to embed that first of all. Or you actually use the mentioned native method, `btoa` - support for that should exist in all major browsers these days. And you will of course also need to decode the data on the server side again, before you can continue processing it.

Comment: i did embed that but i had to stop as I dont understand how to apply the code to my code...